# Custom formatter for custom log level in Python

Tags: python, logging

I have added a custom log level to my Python logger using the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.html) module.

Is it possible to add a **custom formatter** to just this custom log level?

For example, I want just show the message for this custom log level, but additionally timestamps in other log levels.t

Comment: yes, its possible. the python documentation has examples, or, if you provide code example and what's not working, the SO community may be able to help you.

Comment: Can you please point me to an example for a custom formatter for a custom log level? I didn't see any.